# Not receiving FCM notification after sometime

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, background, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented firebase cloud messaging into my chat application, im using retrofit to send message through fcm notification from source user to destination user, everything works fine for sometime even when the app is closed, but after say some hours i don't receive any notification. Why this might be happening? any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look about this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive ?

To keep receiving, when the app is killed, you need to mark your Firebase Service class to not get killed with your main app.

Do something like that (not tested)

```kotlin
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
      applicationContext,
      FCMService.class);

applicationContext.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
       componentName,
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This may also help : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/41#issuecomment-306066751

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware about Don't kill app flag, ill try it. and also will this work for every service class?

Comment: I believe it does, but I'm not sure about it... 
Did this resolve your problem ?

Comment: @AchalUrankara i have the same problem .. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No @Adam I still cannot receive notification after some time when the app is killed.