# Is it possible to run service endlessly in android even after closing the app?

Tags: java, android, networking, websocket

I tried alarm manager to give me notification on a scheduled time but if I want to stay subscribed to my server on a topic, by closing the app, connection will be closed, is there anything I can do to stay connected to my server, using web socket or background services. I've tried background service, but that too stops after sometime when app is closed, nothing happens to stay alive.

Comment: You need a foreground service. They are less likely to be killed by the OS. Besides that, the Workmanager API is your best bet.

Comment: foreground I've tried, but its not good for ux as notification stays there, Ill go through work manager. thanks for your help.

Comment: The "annoying" UX is intentional. Google wants to discourage apps running permanently unless the user is notified of that fact. That's why workmanager and other (more battery-saving) approaches are provided for most of those use cases.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, when i tried to hide that notification manually, later system notification was generated telling me this app is consuming battery.

Answer (score 1):

Use `START_STICKY` in the service class

```java
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and also add this in the manifest:

```xml
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

Comment: I tried start sticky, but when we close the app, service gets killed as well. Im not sure but start sticky used to work back in time, but now they updated considering battery consumption.

Comment: Also add this in menifest where service class define:-

 android:stopWithTask="false"

I hope this will be work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of stopWithTask attr, Ill try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=CjwKCAiA9tyQBhAIEiwA6tdCrCJhbJlvXFZAhJMcgHIk_rMF02kjFx20HD1v-TC5HBtmf7WZi3GxEhoCqU0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&authuser=1) for scheduling task, especially the `OneTime`

Worker will still "running" event if the app is killed.

You could do something like that.

1. Building the Worker Class

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters

class NotifyWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        // Method to trigger an instant notification
        triggerNotification()

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

The worker only need to handle the notification trigger.

2. Building the Work Request

Now create a `OneTimeWorkRequest` because you only need to trigger the notification once.

Alternatively, you could use a `PeriodicWorkRequest` for recurring work.

```kotlin
        val notificationWork = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotifyWorker::class.java)
            .setInitialDelay(delay) // this is when your notification should be triggered 
            .setInputData(inputData) // this is the data you can pass to the NotifyWorker 
            .addTag("notificationWork")
            .build()
```

Now that you have created everything you need to schedule the work, you can just ask the WorkManager to queue it to the list of active tasks from the system:

```
  WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(notificationWork)
```

At this point, the WorkManager will add the work to its queue, then determine when it can run and do the work as specified in the first step. And there you go, your notifications will now trigger on time, regardless of **device restarts**, **app force closes**, and without using a bulky service.

Comment: Thanks for this, but for scheduling tasks I used alarm manager as I mentioned in the question, that would do it for one time task, I would probably change it to work manager but for long running process and getting those changes from my server, is it possible to do that with work manager?

Comment: I'm sorry, I read too fast, and I didn’t get that you wanted to be notified by your server, and not at a specific time.
I don't thing a such thing is possible with WorkManager. You have to use a Service.

Comment: Yeah no problem, thanks for that, ill try service. but the problem is when I close my app service gets killed too, I tried FCM, here is my other question, can you please check this once, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246542/not-receiving-fcm-notification-after-sometime firebase messaging service is also getting killed I think. I don't know how should I tackle this.